# What is better choice for my app - CoreData or plist?

Tags: ios, core-data, plist

I'm making an iPhone app that is like the Apple's "Reminders". It allows user to create reminders, set timers and view / search / reschedule past reminders. Also I'm planning to add iCloud sync. What kind of storage should I use? CoreData or plists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're planning on adding iCloud sync, why not just start with iCloud? If you're using Apple's beta software, you can use CloudKit which has incredibly similar API to CoreData, only it syncs with the users iCloud account. Or, you can upload files (a plist) to their iCloud. Either way, you should start with iCloud if you plan to use it.

As for the question in the title, he says it better than I:
[Should I save in plist or Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964408/should-i-save-in-plist-or-core-data)

Here's more info on [iCloud / CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.html)